# how to change recycler view items smoothly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a recycler view in my layout, at first it will be filled by data which is stored in local database, and then after a few second it will be updated using server.

the problem is when it updates, items of recycler view change suddenly, how can I set an animation for recycler view that change the items smoothly?

I notify my recycler view just like this:

```
 fun add(list: List<BestStockModel>) {
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(list)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, list.size)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a better way for you do so, you can use `ListAdapter` [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter).
Using `ListAdapter` you can simply submit a new list and the adapter will calculate the diff between the old one and the new one and add need animations for new/changed/deleted items.

It can detect the diff using simple callbacks that you provide to it.
Here's an example that you can use as a reference:

```kotlin
class HomeMoviesAdapter : ListAdapter<Movie, MoviesViewHolder>(
    //note the following callbacks, ListAdapter uses them
    // in order to find diff between the old and new items.
    object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Movie>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean =
            oldItem.title == newItem.title //this can be a unique ID for the item

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean =
            oldItem == newItem
    }
) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MoviesViewHolder {
        val v: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.movies_item_view, parent, false)
        return MoviesViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MoviesViewHolder, position: Int) {
       //your binding logic goes here as usual.
    }
}
```

And then from where you have the list (ex: fragment) you can do the following:

```kotlin
adapter.submit(newList)
```

And that's it for the list adapter to do the needed animations for you.

**There's one gotcha though**: if submitted the same list reference, the adapter will consider it the same as the old list, meaning it won't trigger the diff calculations. Note the following example:

```kotlin
//the following is a bad practice DO NOT do this!
val list: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)

adapter.submitList(list)

list.clear()
list.add(7)
adapter.submitList(list) //nothing will happen, since it's the same ref
```

Compare that to the following:

```kotlin
//the following is good practice, try to do the following!
adapter.submitList(listOf(1, 2, 3))
adapter.submitList(listOf(7)) //will delete all the old items, insert 7 and will also trigger the need animations correctly.
```

Although they both seem similar, they quite different: the second one submits a totally new list "reference-wise" to the adapter, which will cause the `ListAdapter` to trigger the calculations correctly.